# How do I use <input type="file" id="myFile"> to upload a CSV file?

Tags: meteor, stream, input-type-file, import-csv

I am using the **fast-csv packaged for Meteor**  installed:

```
meteor add chhib:fast-csv
```

My app is only able to open up a csv file "**my.csv**" at a predetermined location. The problem is it doesn't allow me to choose any other file. Find below my code:

**client/main.js**

```
var stream = fs.createReadStream("my.csv");

  var csvStream = csv()
  .on("data", function(data){
     console.log(data);
   })

  .on("end", function(){
     console.log("done");
   });

stream.pipe(csvStream);
```

I would like to redesign the app so that I am able to read/upload a csv file of my choice, via an File Upload button.

Find below my **File Upload Button** html code:

**client/main.html**

`<input type="file" id="myFile">`

How do I get the contents uploaded from the **File uploaded button** into the **stream** variable?

`var stream = fs.createReadStream("uploaded file");`

Answer (score 0):

You can use simply js FileReader for reading the contents of uploaded file.

Add below code in your file upload event handler :

```
var file = document.getElementById("myFile").files[0];
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function(fileLoadEvent) {
 // file contents are available in reader.result
  var stream = reader.result; // saving file contents in stream variable       

};
reader.readAsBinaryString(file);
```